# Postgreslq Explain analyse : hidden time

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I've a long query and `explain analyze` isn't helping.

Version of PostgreSQL : 9.1

The current plan:

http://explain.depesz.com/s/sWG

The query :

```
SELECT temps_mois.rfoperyea      AS c0, 
       dwhinv.dwhinv___rfovsnide AS c1, 
       rfoadv_1.rfoadvsup        AS c2, 
       rfoadv_2.rfoadvsup        AS c3, 
       rsaaev_3.rsaaevsup        AS c4, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '17' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m0, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '18' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m1, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '15' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m2, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '16' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m3, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '20' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m4, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '17' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m5, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '18' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m6, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '15' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m7, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '19' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m8, 
       Sum(( CASE 
               WHEN dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                    AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '16' THEN dwhinv.dwhinvqte 
               ELSE 0 
             END ))              AS m9 
FROM   rfoper_temps_mois AS temps_mois, 
       dwhinv AS dwhinv, 
       rfoadv AS rfoadv_1, 
       rfoadv AS rfoadv_2, 
       rsaaev AS rsaaev_3 
WHERE  ( temps_mois.rfoper___rforefide = 'REF' ) 
       AND ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rforefide = 'REF' 
             AND ( ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                     AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '17' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '18' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '15' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'LABO' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '16' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '20' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '17' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '18' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '15' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '19' ) 
                    OR ( dwhinv.dwhinv___rfodomide = 'ANAPATH' 
                         AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfoindide = '16' ) ) ) 
       AND dwhinv.dwhinvdtd = temps_mois.rfoperdtd 
       AND temps_mois.rfoperyea IN ( '2011', '2012' ) 
       AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rfovsnide = 'version' 
       AND ( rfoadv_1.rfoadv___rfovdeide = 'STRC' 
             AND rfoadv_1.rfoadvrvs = 1 
             AND rfoadv_1.rfoadv___rforefide = 'REF' ) 
       AND dwhinv.dwhinv_d2rfodstide = rfoadv_1.rfoadvinf 
       AND rfoadv_1.rfoadvsup = 'REF' 
       AND ( rfoadv_2.rfoadv___rfovdeide = 'STRC_REF' 
             AND rfoadv_2.rfoadvrvs = 1 
             AND rfoadv_2.rfoadv___rforefide = 'REF' ) 
       AND dwhinv.dwhinv_p2rfodstide = rfoadv_2.rfoadvinf 
       AND rfoadv_2.rfoadvsup IN ( '01', '04', '05', '06', 
                                   '07', '99', 'REF', 'CR2107', 
                                   'CR2108', 'CR2109', 'CR2110', 'CR2111', 
                                   'CR2114', 'CR2116', 'CR2126', 'CR4101', 
                                   'CR4201' ) 
       AND ( rsaaev_3.rsaaev___rsavedide = 'PRESTA_ACTE' 
             AND rsaaev_3.rsaaevrvs = 1 
             AND rsaaev_3.rsaaev___rforefide = 'REF' ) 
       AND dwhinv.dwhinv___rsaedtide = rsaaev_3.rsaaevinf 
       AND rsaaev_3.rsaaevsup IN ( 'PRISE_EN_CHARGE', 'REG_EXT', 
                                   'REG_HOSPI_SEANCE' ) 
GROUP  BY temps_mois.rfoperyea, 
          dwhinv.dwhinv___rfovsnide, 
          rfoadv_1.rfoadvsup, 
          rfoadv_2.rfoadvsup, 
          rsaaev_3.rsaaevsup
```

It seems like several seconds elapse between the HashJoin and the Hashaggregate. Hashjoin takes 1200 to 1600ms. With the HashAggregate it jumps to 5645ms.

Might anyone else who ever encountered this problem be able to explain the difference?

Comment: I cleaned up your post and plan a bit, but it would help if you rephrased and reformatted it the way you'd want it to be, along with your actual schema, query, and what you're trying to achieve. As things are, it's a bit hard to follow.

Comment: That's only *part of the query plan* - you've cut parts of it off. Please show the full plan. For big plans like this please past the plan to http://explain.depesz.com/ and provide a link to that as well as including the in-text copy. It's very helpful for examining big plans. Also: **PostgreSQL version and exact query text please**.   Comment here when you've edited your question to correct those issues so that Denis and I are notified of the change.

Comment: I use your site, thanx for the tip. I've add the query, but it is partly generated so i will be hard to modify.

Answer (score 1):

The posted plan does not seem to match your description.  For example, there is no "actual time" of 5645ms in the plan given, perhaps the top node was missing from your copy and paste.

But anyway, the time between 1600 and 5645 would be the time from when HashAggregate read the last row it needs to read, but cannot yet generate its first row.  For example, because it needs to do some bulk operations on the data it read.

Comment: I've added information like better query plan and query. I indeed forgot the two most important lines :). What sort of opreation coul the database do between two node in query plan ?